# Finished basement question

Tags: waterproofing, basement-refinishing

Some background. I have french drains in half my basement, in the area where my water pump is.  I just installed a laminate floor, and put up walls.

My question:  I recently had some water get in my basement when my pump ran nonstop for 6 hours and flooded my yard, it only leaked in one spot away from where the water pipes enter the house. I am assuming it was due to the insulation being accidently shoved into the French drain and water was sucked up and went across my floor.  I'm curious if I should use silicon caulk and run a bead along the bottom of my 2x4 so if this randomly does happen again, the water would have to rise above the 2x4 to enter the basement and then be above to floor so as to not get water below my new floor. If anyone has any tips for resealing where the water pipes enter the house too that would be great as the previous seal got water behind it and fell off leaving a 2 foot by 3 foot area around the pipe that sounds hollow.

Comment: Inside fixes are only temporary at best.  For a good long term fix it should be sealed from the outside.  Water on top of flooring will get underneath.  Would extend the drain pipe for pump further away from house or fix slope of ground.

Comment: There is a HUGE difference between water wicking up through the walls and also if the walls are block or poured concrete with shrinkage cracks.  Shrinkage cracks can be sealed with polyurethane, but blocks holding water is bad news.  Are there any signs of constant moisture in the bottom couple of feet in the walls?

Comment: No signs of moisture on walls at all which is why I felt comfortable finishing it off.  There is a drain hole in the corner of the basement which drains into a stream in the back. Usually water it in but never seen any water on walls or floor before.  Obly reason there was water was because my well pump flooded my yard with thousands of gallons of water and the wall where the pipes enter had too much pressure and water seaped in there.  The French drains did there job though.

Comment: Since I fixed the well I haven't seen any water anywhere

Comment: I don't quite understand where is your french drain located -  why it is half of your basement, is it located outside of your exterior wall or inside the basement? Then, the "yard" (outside of the building?) was flooded, the leak started from a location adjacent to the "water pipes" entering the house, what are the water pipes, how heigh are the pipes above the floor, was the leak is around the pipes or from the wall-floor joint? My last question - what kind of wall it is, block masonry or concrete? Please clarify the best you can.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing water to seep into your basement occasionally and sit behind your wood sole plate is a bad idea. This can create a breeding ground for mold and dryrot.

Moisture is either coming up from below (a rising water table) or its coming from the surrounding ground water in the saturated soil, or both.

If it comes up from a rising water table, it will enter the living space from below through the crack between the foundation wall and slab.

If it comes from the surrounding ground water, it COULD enter the living space through the wall, especially if the EXTERIOR side of the foundation wall is not sealed properly.
Either way the moisture enters the living space it will need to be collected and disposed. I think the best way to collect it is on the exterior side of the foundation wall in drainrock and a perf pipe laid 6”-8” below the interior basement slab.

To keep the subsurface water from seeping through the wall, I recommend installing a moisture barrier on the exterior side of the foundation wall and install a 2” thick plastic mesh on the wall to allow water to flow down to the perf pipe. If dirt is allowed to be backfilled against the wall, the dirt could hold the moisture giving it a chance to seep through the wall.

Once collected it needs to be disposed by extending a solid pipe over an embankment or in a collection well and pumped away.

This may be the most expensive method (collecting subsurface water on the exterior side of the exterior wall) of solving the problem, but it’s sure to work.